# Display results when a string is not in a range

Tags: google-sheets

[On this worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Svermjq37-CjIQJxQLvE5CXiBcDTsboQDKTPk8euY6w/edit#gid=0) I am trying to see if the data in column B is not in the lookup list in column C. If the data from column B is not there, then I want to print the respective value from column A. I have the following formula in column E:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(B2:B,JOIN("|",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(C2:C,COUNTA(C2:C),1)))=false)
```

The issue is that I have blank rows in column C and the `REGEXMATCH` is counting the blank as a `.*`.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you don't want "classic" to match "as",  use `"^" & join(...) & "$"`instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when forming regular expressions using `join("|", C2:C)`, it is imperative to avoid blank cells in the range.  To do this, `filter` the range:

```
join("|", filter(C2:C, len(C2:C)))
```

The reason for using `len` here is that it returns 0, interpreted as False, for empty cells, and nonzero numbers, interpreted as True, for other cells.